# how to convert NSMutableDictionary into NSString?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to convert `NSMutableDictionary` into `NSString`. But it inserts "\" in my string. I am using the following code to convert `NSMutableDictionary` into `NSString`.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inspectionJson options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"ns data is %@",jsonData);
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"final":json};
```

Here,

```
NSMutableDictionary *inspectionJson = {"name":"abc","profession":"IT","images":()}
```

It gives me output as

```
dict = {final = "{\"name\":\"abc\",\"profession\":\"IT\",\"images\":[]}";}
```

My required output is

```
{final = "{"name":"abc","profession":"IT","images":[]}";}
```

How can I get my required output? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called [Escape sequences in C (from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Comment: Oh one more thing, why you use `\n` for new line instead of just pressing enter ???

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Comment: Please tell me is there any other alternative to get output like NSDictionary *dict = final = {"name":"abc","profession":"IT","images":[]};

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *inspectionJson = @{@"name":@"abc",@"profession":@"IT",@"images":@[]};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inspectionJson options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"ns data is %@",jsonData);
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"json string:%@", json);
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"final":json};
```

If you run this code you can see the actual json in the console.

**Please for the sake of programming don't hover the mouse over the `json` variable and expect the string without escaping the special character in a string.**

Let me explain you a bit more. Suppose you have a string

```
NSString *s1 = @"Make said, he is going to Paris";
```

Suddenly you find out hey I'm missing double quotes, so you changed the statement as below.

```
NSString *s1 = @"Mike said, "he is going to Paris"";
```

But suddenly compiler throws the error on your face, "Hey you can't do that!"

It's because `"` is being used to define string and you can't use quotes within the same string, just like nested comments `/* /* */ */`

So what will you do? Here is your saviour [Escape Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) which lets you to use the special characters within you string.

So here is the final string

```
NSString *s1 = @"Mike said, \"he is going to Paris\"";
```

Comment: i require unescape string in NSDictionary object as I have to send this data to server using AFNetworking

Comment: Please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: @NishiBansal: Try Inder's code adding `NSLog(@"final: %@",dict[@"final"]);`. You should see it is correct.

Comment: Yes it gives me correct output. But it returns me NSString object not NSDictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

`"` need to escape in a string, when use it(`/`) will not appear.

You can use this code to test:

```
NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"final"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use two ways

NSString *dict =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aDictionary];

or

you can use `description` method of `NSMutableDictionary`

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aDictionary];, then how can I convert this NSString to NSDictionary. As I require NSDictionary object.

Comment: dict is NSString object but I require dict to be NSDictionary object